# Adding data to a container while iterating and also removing for a certain condition

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have vector where data will be added by invoking a function pointer from outside, say main(). The iteration process will start upon adding data to the vector and will continue until the vector is found to be empty. The iteration process will also remove data from the vector for a certain condition. While iterating, data will be added randomly. What I tried to do, created a separate thread to add data while the iteration process is running in main thread. But I can't achieve that, because while the loop is executing the adding process is not happening. Just need your kind help here. Following is my code:

```
======= TASKMANAGER.HPP ===============
#ifndef TASKMANAGER_H
#define TASKMANAGER_H

#include <vector>
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>
#include <functional>

class TaskManager
{
public:
    TaskManager();
    void checkVec();
    void addToVec(const int val);

    std::function<void(int)> mValueAdder;
    bool mStop;
private:
    std::vector<int> mIntVec;
    std::atomic_bool mChecking;
    std::recursive_mutex mVecModifier;
    size_t mVecSize;
};

#endif // TASKMANAGER_H

======== TASKMANAGER.CPP ==============
#include "taskmanager.h"

#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;

TaskManager::TaskManager() : mChecking(false), mStop(false), mVecSize(0)
{
    mValueAdder = [this](const int val) -> void {
        std::thread t(&TaskManager::addToVec, this, val);
        if(t.joinable())
        {
            t.join();
        }
        if(this->mChecking == false)
        {
            std::cout << "Value of mChecking: " << mChecking << std::endl;
            this->checkVec();
        }
    };
}

void TaskManager::checkVec()
{
    mChecking = true;
    do {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
        std::cout << "checking" << std::endl;
        uint16_t idx = 0;
        while(idx < mVecSize)
        {
            std::cout << mIntVec[idx] << std::endl;
            if(mIntVec[idx] == 1)
            {
                std::lock_guard<decltype(mVecModifier)> lock(mVecModifier);
                mIntVec.erase(mIntVec.begin() + idx);
                mVecSize--;
                continue;
            }
            idx++;
        }
    } while(!mStop && (mChecking = !mIntVec.empty()));
}

void TaskManager::addToVec(const int val)
{
    std::lock_guard<decltype(mVecModifier)> lock(mVecModifier);
    mIntVec.push_back(val);
    mVecSize++;
    std::cout << "Val: " << val << " added to vector" << std::endl;
}
```

======= MAIN.CPP ===============

```
#include <taskmanager.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    TaskManager tm;
    tm.mValueAdder(10);
    tm.mValueAdder(20);
    tm.mStop = true;
    return 0;
}

======== OUTPUT =========
Val: 10 added to vector
Value of mChecking: 0
checking
10
checking
10
checking
10
checking
10
....
....

That means, the value is not adding to the vector while the loop is running.
```

Comment: Your program is effectively single-threaded (there is no concurrency) because every time you start a thread, you then immediately wait for it to finish.

Comment: Your loop removes `1`s and stops when the vector is empty. Your vector only contains a `10`. When does the loop terminate?

Comment: I have added that thread just to insert into the vector, when the insertion finishes, it will terminate, I just wanted to concurrently add data to the vector. The loop will remove all 1 s and it will only terminate when the vector becomes empty, another process (which I didn't include here) running in another thread, will make the contents of the vector to 1

Comment: I can't figure out how to insert data randomly when that loop is running indefinitely, thanks.